# Servlet Redirect failed, all parameters doesn't show up in the URL

Tags: java, rest, jsp, servlets

I have 2 java web projects, One is IdentityService and the other is Client. Client has **login.jsp** that post the data from the form to the **LoginServlet.java** in IdentityService. **LoginServlet.java** will authenticate the user login and send back token, id and username via url to the **login.jsp**. After that, **login.jsp** will add it into session for further use.

But, the url redirected from **LoginServlet** doesn't contain any parameter and when I tried to print it, all the parameters are null. Here is my code :

**Login.jsp**

```
<%  
String user = request.getParameter("username");
String pass = request.getParameter("password");
String error = "";

if(user != null && pass != null && !user.equals("") && !pass.equals("")){
    String url = "http://localhost:8082/IdentityServices/LoginServlet";
    URL iurl = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)iurl.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // Send POST output.
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    java.io.DataOutputStream printout = new java.io.DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
    String content = "username=" + user + "&password=" + pass;
    printout.writeBytes (content);
    printout.flush (); 
    printout.close ();

    //retrieve response from IS
    java.io.BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(
        (java.io.InputStream) connection.getContent()));

    out.println("<h2>Successful Authentication using REST</h2>");
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(line + "<br>");
    }

    //session.setAttribute("token", request.getParameter("token"));
    //session.setAttribute("uname", request.getParameter("username"));
    //session.setAttribute("userid", request.getParameter("userid"));
    //response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/StackExchangeClient/catalog.jsp");
} else if(user != null && pass != null && (user.equals("") || pass.equals(""))){
    // handle empty form or incomplete form 
    error = "Please enter username and password !";
}
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body class="body-center helvetica">
<div class = "text-align-center arial">
        <h1><span class="color-red">Sale</span><span class="color-blue">Project</span></h1>
</div>

<div class = "border-bottom ">
        <h2>Please login</h2>
</div>

<div>
        <form method="POST" action="login.jsp">
            <span class="font-small">Email or Username</span><br><input type="text" name="username" class="input-text">
            <span class="font-small">Password</span><br><input type="password" name="password"  class="input-text"><br><br>
            <strong style="color:red;"><%out.println(error);%></strong><br>
            <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" name="login" class="float-right button">
        </form>
</div>  
<br><br><br>
<p class="font-small"><strong>Don't have an account yet? Register <a href = "register.jsp" class="link"> here </a></strong></p>
    <!-- for debugging -->
    Hello <b><%= request.getParameter("uname") %></b>!
    Hello <b><%= request.getParameter("token") %></b>!
    Hello <b><%= request.getParameter("userid") %></b>!
</body>
```

**LoginServlet.java**

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String user = request.getParameter("username");
    String pass = request.getParameter("password");
    if(user != null && pass != null && !user.equals("") && !pass.equals("")){
        try {
            //creating connection with the database 
            Connection con = DB.connect();
            PreparedStatement ps =con.prepareStatement
                          ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?;");
            ps.setString(1, user);
            ps.setString(2, pass);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){ 
                // user exist, generate token
                String token = getToken();
                String username = rs.getString("username");
                int uid = rs.getInt("id");
                response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/StackExchangeClient/login.jsp?"+"token="+token+"&"+"uname="+username+"&"+"userid="+uid);
            } else {
                // user doesn't exist
                out.println("tidak ada");
            }
        } catch( SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

public String getToken(){
    Random random = new SecureRandom();
    String token = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);

    return token;
}

public void insertTokenDB(String token, String username) throws SQLException{
    try {
        Connection con = DB.connect();
        Timestamp now = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
        Statement newPS = con.createStatement();
        newPS.executeUpdate("UPDATE user SET Token='"+token+"' ,createAt='"+now+"' WHERE username ='"+username+"'");
        con.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got an login exception!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I don't get it, why it doesn't redirect me with the parameters I have given....

Comment: Because you never perform a redirect. There are a number of issues, but most important fact is that you just call the LoginServlet from the **server-side**. You must send a HTTP redirect response to the client instead

Comment: Following @home's first comment, why do you perform redirections with full, hard-coded URLs? Are the JSP and the servlet deployed on different web contexts?

Comment: Thanks, now I see the problem and have solved it using HTTP header field